# Column header validation with different sheets using macros

Tags: excel, vba, merge, worksheet

In Excel, I have 4 column headers (`Id`, `Name`, `Age`, `Place`).

I have 3 Excel worksheets with same column headers and different data.

I want to make a consolidated worksheet and the constraint is I have to check whether the column header is the same in all 3 worksheets and move it into the consolidated worksheet.

- In the 1st worksheet I have values in the first row.
- In 2nd worksheet, the first row is empty and the second row has data.
- In 3rd worksheet, the first and second rows are empty and the 3rd row has data.
- The 4th worksheet is the consolidated one. I want all 3 worksheet's data in this sheet.

How to do it with macros in `vba`?

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your 1st badge!) and see "[ask]", and also the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.  If you have a *specific* problem with a certain section of your code, you can [edit] your post to share an **[mcve]** as well as sample data and some background info.  Here are some  [tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

There's [built-in functionality](http://%20https//support.office.com/article/consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-007ce8f4-2fae-4fea-9ee5-a0b2c9e36d9b) for data consolidation.

You'll need to move your data so it's all on the same row but in the end will probably be much easier than writing code from scratch.

---

### How to consolidate

Follow these steps to consolidate several worksheets into a master worksheet:

1. If you haven't already, set up the data in each constituent sheet by doing the following:

   - Ensure that each range of data is in list format. Each column must have a label (header) in the first row and contain similar data. There must be no blank rows or columns anywhere in the list.
   - Put each range on a separate worksheet, but don't enter anything in the master worksheet where you plan to consolidate the data. Excel will do this for you.
   - Ensure that each range has the same layout.
2. In the master worksheet, click the upper-left cell of the area where you want the consolidated data to appear.

   > **Note:** To avoid overwriting existing data in the master worksheet, ensure that you leave enough cells to the right and below this cell for the consolidated data.
3. Click <kbd>Data</kbd> → <kbd>Consolidate</kbd> (in the **Data Tools** group).
   [image: Data Tools group on the Data tab]
4. In the **Function** box, click the summary function that you want Excel to use to consolidate the data. The default function is [SUM](https://support.office.com/article/sum-function-043e1c7d-7726-4e80-8f32-07b23e057f89).

   Here is an example in which three worksheet ranges have been chosen:

   [image: Data Consolidation dialog]
5. Select your data.

   [image: img]

> ***More information and the remaining instructions are at the [source](http://%20https//support.office.com/article/consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-007ce8f4-2fae-4fea-9ee5-a0b2c9e36d9b).***

---

If you want to automate the process, record a macro as you performs the necessary steps and then you can edit as required.

See: [**Recording a Macro to Generate Code**](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/recording-a-macro-to-generate-code) as well as [**Revising Recorded Visual Basic Macros**](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/revising-recorded-visual-basic-macros). If you're not familiar with Excel (or whatever you're planning on automating with VBA), do that before attempting VBA.

This VBA tutorial is highly recommended: [**Excel VBA For Beginners**](//www.homeandlearn.org/) and [**Microsoft's Documentation**](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/vba-language-reference).

Comment: I followed your method. But this method is possible only for integer datas. The data in the column ‘place’ is not copied into consolidated sheet.